# How do I know which variable comes first in facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot, facet-grid

I'm working with the titanic library in R, I'm using ggplot to create a grid of density plots for age filled by survival status with count on the y-axis, faceted by sex and passenger class.

Here's my code

```
titanic %>%
  ggplot(aes(Age, ..count.., fill = Survived)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.2) +
  facet_grid(Pclass~Sex)
```

Will there be a major difference if I switched the variables around in facet_grid? Both facet_grid(Pclass~Sex) and facet_grid(Sex~Pclass) gave me reasonable looking plots. Which one should I use to base my analysis on?

Answer (score 1):

From the website https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_grid.html it says "`facet_grid()` forms a matrix of panels defined by row and column faceting variables." so I suspect `facet_grid(Pclass~Sex)` will have `Pclass` on the rows and `Sex` on the columns and vice-versa. So they will both show the same information just orientated differently.